# Performance Object cannot be seen in Windows 7

Tags: delphi, windows-7, performancecounter, performance

I wish to register some of status of my application as a performance object, so that I can monitor its performance by utilising the Windows Performance Monitor.

But I had a problem with Windows 7: the performance object cannot be seen in the list of Performance Monitor, even if my application is running.

My code is exactly the same as the Delphi project in this tutorial:
http://www.wehlou.com/Code/perfmon/index.htm

However, the solution provided in this tutorial doesn't work in Windows 7 either.

Such solution works fine in <strike>Windows XP and</strike> 2003.

I don't know if there are some changes in Windows 7 which makes my performance object missing.

Please help. Thanks a heap in advance.

Comment: What is the Performance Object you refer to?  Can you provide a brief code snippet illustrating its use?

Comment: You need to provide your code here, instead of saying "my code is like something". First, if the outside link is down or goes away, your question is meaningless. Second, we can't see what you've actually done that isn't working. Please edit your post and provide the code here; without it, your question is unanswerable. Thanks. :)

Comment: Welhou's PerfMon doesn't work perfectly in Windows XP.

Answer (score 3):

Is your Windows 7 computer a 64-bits machine? You may have to provide both a 32 and 64 bits version:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371636(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

**The short answer:**

Yes you can fix manually the 2 object performance counters (DeltaCount & RawCount) issue under Windows 7 x32. The 2 files generated by PerfMonClient.exe are usable (namely symfile.h and symfile.ini).

Nota: Refer to MSDN for the usage of `lodctr.exe`.

Prior to that an entry to the registry as follows should created:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\PerfMonClient\Performance]
"Open"="PerfData_Open"
"Close"="PerfData_Close"
"Collect"="PerfData_Collect"
"Library"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,50,\
  00,65,00,72,00,66,00,4d,00,6f,00,6e,00,44,00,4c,00,4c,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,\
  6c,00,00,00
```

Nota: Library point to %SystemRoot%\System32\PerfMonDLL.dll (location of the performance DLL).

Any attempt to install and/or uninstall them using PerfMonClient.exe App doesn't work even under Windows XP. Forget about that.

---

**Look an feel:**

[image: PerMonClient1]

[image: PerMonClient2]

---

**Listing**

symfile.h:

```
#define OBJECT_1   0
#define DEVICE_COUNTER_1   2
#define DEVICE_COUNTER_2   4
```

symfile.ini:

```
[info]
drivername=PerfMonClient
symbolfile=symfile.h
[languages]
009=English
[text]
OBJECT_1_009_NAME=PerfMonTest Performance Counters
OBJECT_1_009_HELP=A demo application for your unbridled pleasure
DEVICE_COUNTER_1_009_NAME=RawCount
DEVICE_COUNTER_1_009_HELP=A count of something that goes up and down
DEVICE_COUNTER_2_009_NAME=DeltaCount
DEVICE_COUNTER_2_009_HELP=Something going up all the time, Windows shows difference per time unit
```